# Timeout/Cancel long running elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

What is a good way to timeout/cancel a expensive query in elasticsearch?

ES Cluster' data storage capacity is about 100T off which 60T is used. Shard size is 20G.
`search.default_search_timeout` and `search.cancel_after_time_interval` were set to 1sec and didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The search timeout can be configurable at query time and also it can be configurable via cluster settings to apply all your searches.

```
GET test_index/_search
{
  "timeout": "60s", 
  "query": {},
  "aggs": {}
}

PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.default_search_timeout": "60s"
  }
}
```

Note: The query timeout is not guaranteed. In some cases (especially in very large indices) the timeout operation may fail.
To set a cluster-wide default timeout for all search requests, configure search.default_search_timeout using the cluster settings API. This global timeout duration is used if no timeout argument is passed in the request. If the global search timeout expires before the search request finishes, the request is cancelled using task cancellation. The search.default_search_timeout setting defaults to -1 (no timeout).

> please note that the timeout is per shard not per request

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-your-data.html

As you experienced it's not guaranteed the timeout. To protect your cluster and drop heavy queries you need to use an external application. I recommend you check the Search gateway.

https://opster.com/opensearch-search-gateway/

[image]